# boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 2 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I'm trying to solve Dimensionality reduction using PCA and T-SNE. I am stuck at this step. the error is " IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 180000 but corresponding boolean dimension is 60000" i tried looking up online for possible solutions and i found solutions where it said to lower my version of tensior flow and keras and i did it but it did'nt work. i tried to look for more possible solutions but didnt find anything relevant.I am adding my code to this Question. Can anyone guide me with this?

```
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

%matplotlib inline

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [12, 9]

(x_train, x_test), (y_train, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

train = np.concatenate((x_train, y_train))
test = np.concatenate((x_test, y_test))

(x_train.shape)

y_train

print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)
print(y_test.shape)

train=np.concatenate((x_train,y_train))
test=np.concatenate((x_test,y_test))
print(train.shape)
print(test.shape)

pca = PCA(n_components=2)

%%time
reduced = pca.fit_transform(train.reshape(-1, 32 * 32))

for i in range(10):
  num = reduced[test == i]
  plt.scatter(num[:, 0], num[:, 1], s=5, label=f'{i}')

plt.legend()
plt.show() 

IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 180000 but corresponding boolean dimension is 60000
```